# Как перенести одно измерение многомерного массива в одномерный массив?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Как можно имея данные `X` и `Y` для трехмерного массива создать одномерный массив?

Что-то на подобие:

```java
String A[X][Y][] = String B[];
```

И вот этот фрагмент со словами мне нужно записать в отдельный одномерный массив:

```java
String words[][][] = {
{{""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}},
{{""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}},
{{""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}},
{{"Пожарный", "Учитель", "Ученый"}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}},
{{""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}}};
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Добавьте в вопрос пример.

Comment: Добавил и наверное сделал немного понятнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String words[][][] = {{{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{"Пожарный", "Учитель","Ученый"},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}}};
String[] res = Arrays.copyOf(words[3][0], words[3][0].length);
```

или если массив у вас уже есть:

```
String words [] [] [] = {{{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{"Пожарный", "Учитель","Ученый"},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}},
                        {{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""},{""}}};
String[] res = new String[words[3][0].length];
System.arraycopy(words[3][0], 0, res, 0, words[3][0].length);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Ты очень сильно мне помог!